# Cheapest way to serve static file

Tags: scaling, amazon-cloudfront

I've developed a 3rd party app that I have integrated on a site that gets about 2-3 million hits per day
I'm serving the required assets (css, js and image file) from AWS Cloudfront
The costs are starting to add up, and I'm wondering the cheapest way to deliver static assets

I have a micro instance, but I'm not sure if that could handle that many requests (even though it's static content). Think it could?

Or have any recommendations on mirror cdns like cloudfront that are cheaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Cloudflare is cheaper for your requirements, take a look:

[Cloudflare Plans](http://www.cloudflare.com/plans)

Comment: I looked into it, but to be honest, I'm super confused at what service CloudFlare actually offers. I got the feeling it's a DNS service that also provides a CDN?

Comment: Among other things, it offers a [CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn) and it is [very simple to setup](http://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflares-free-cdn-and-you).

Comment: But to use it, I need to route my DNS through them, yeh?

Comment: Yes, and then they take care of the rest

Comment: That's my hesitation. Unique to have to route DNS to make use of a CDN. Will give it a go and see what comes of it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change your DNS to point to CloudFalare, if your hosting server fails to respond your site will be unavailable, so at the end of the day if your hosting server is unreliable, you won't be having much success.